# how to load spark ml model while using grpc dependencies?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dependencies, sbt, grpc

i have a problem about load spark model.
that totally works fine while not using gRPC dependencies.

this is my main.scala

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidatorModel
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

    object lr_model {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("ml model").master("local[*]").getOrCreate();

    val model = CrossValidatorModel.load("C:/Users/.....................")
    def testing(subject:String):String = {
        val datatest = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("CATEGORY_SOCIAL",subject))).toDF("labelss","subjects")
        var result = model.transform(datatest).head().getDouble(6)
        return result 
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println(testing("aaaa"))    
        spark.stop()
    }
}
```

and this is my build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

PB.targets in Compile := Seq(
  scalapb.gen() -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value
)

val scalapbVersion =
    scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion
val grpcJavaVersion =
    scalapb.compiler.Version.grpcJavaVersion

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    // spark
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.1" ,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.1" ,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.3.1" ,

    // protobuf
    "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime" % scalapbVersion % "protobuf"

    //for grpc
    //"io.grpc" % "grpc-netty" % grpcJavaVersion
    //"com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime-grpc" % scalapbVersion
)
```

but while i used gprc dependencies that give me an error like this.

```
18/07/18 12:59:08 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at ReadWrite.scala:387
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:312)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:200)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
```

its bug from grpc or my code was wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Spark is using Guava 14.0.1. gRPC-Java requires Guava 20 or later. The method Spark is calling was a `@Beta` API (which should never have been used from a library) which was deprecated in Guava 15.0, released in September 2013, and deleted in Guava 17.0, released in April 2014. You'll need to file an issue against Spark to update their code to use/support newer versions of Guava.